# Axios.get() request returning undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

In the below code Iam trying to use axios get request from `await axios.get('/products/api')`
is only working i can see the data in the console but for`await axios.get('/users/api')`Undefined is being returned on the console but when i try get request through Postman i can get the results .Iam stuck here.

''' const [userdata, setuserdata] = useState([]);
const [products, setproducts] = useState([]);

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
        
        const { users } = await axios.get('/users/api')
        setuserdata(users);

        const { data } = await axios.get('/products/api')
        setproducts(data);
    }
    fetchUserData();



}, []);
console.log(products)
console.log(userdata)
```

Comment: instead of "const {users}" try "const users" and check in console.log(users).
maybe users is not returning from server or returning with different name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update your code to this:**

```
const users = await axios.get('/users/api');
setuserdata(users.data);

const products = await axios.get('/products/api');
setproducts(products.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you destructure your response console.log the response.
I mean try:

```
const users = await axios.get('/users/api');
console.log(users)
```

It could be that users is not part of the default axios data object.
If you still get undefined, then you need to double check that your api is returning the response (POSTMAN).

Answer (score 1):

Believe what you're trying to do is:

```
const [userdata, setUserData] = useState([])
const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
        const users = await axios.get('/users/api')
        setUserData([...userdata, users])

        const data = await axios.get('/products/api')
        setProducts([...products, data])
    }
    fetchUserData()
}, [userdata, products])

console.log(products)
console.log(userdata)
```

If you just use `[]` on the `useEffect` it will only run once at the beginning but per memory React will throw a warning for `products` and `userdata`.

Think they'd also work better in their own `useEffect`. You could even make your code cleaner by creating a function and passing the path in to the function. Like:

```
const getData = async (path) => await axios.get(`/${path}/api`)
```